# Select Command not working while run shell scripts on remote machine

Tags: bash, ssh, scripts

I want to run my shell script on a remote machine and I need user want to give value for some variable for that we use Read command while run script on local machine but I use the same command while run the script on remote machine but it's not working for me. How to use Read command for run script on remote machine?

sample code :

```
restore (){
        echo "Restore"
}

deploy () {
        echo "Deploy"
}


echo "Select any option to proceed..."
read opt
case $opt in

        restore)
        restore;
        break;;

        deploy)
        deploy;
        break;;
esac
```

This code work fine for when run scripts on local machine.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: In what way is it not working? Please edit your post to include the output.

Comment: While running the shell script I can't give the option to select any one of the above options. The shell scripts ends

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686360/command-here-shell-idiom-resulting-in-redirection-unexpected) can help. You should use a parameter instead of select option with user interaction.

Comment: You don't need to use named FIFOs to redirect the standard output of one command to standard input of another You can just use anonymous pipes like so: `cat FILES... | ssh [...]`. If you only have one file to redirect, you don't even need `cat` and a pipe. Just redirect the file directly to the target process: `ssh [...] < FILE`. (See [muru's answer](/a/712716/175814) for a reason, why neither work here.)

Answer (score 4):

If you tell `bash` to read commands from `stdin`, which is what the `-s` option does, and then redirect its stdin, you cannot provide input via stdin any longer.

You should it as a normal script:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.116 bash /root/BackupShellScript/remote.sh
```

And source `/usr/local/etc/BackupShellScript/configuration.conf` from your script, instead of hacking your way around with `cat` and process substitution.

Answer (score 1):

That script doesn't work even locally - never mind with ssh.

The problem is just that you put your result into `option` and then use `case $opt`.  So change `option` to `opt` and all is well.

```
#!/bin/bash

restore (){
        echo "Restore"
}

deploy () {
        echo "Deploy"
}

echo "Select any option to proceed..."
select opt in "deploy" "restore" ; do
case $opt in

        restore)
        restore;
        break;;

        deploy)
        deploy;
        break;;
esac
done
```

Comment: I change option to opt in **select option in "deploy" "restore" ; do** . After that also it is not working for command **ssh root@192.168.1.116 "bash -s" < <(cat /usr/local/etc/BackupShellScript/configuration.conf /root/BackupShellScript/remote.sh)**