# How to use Read command in shell script while run script on remote machine

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, scripts

I want to run my shell script on a remote machine and I need user want to give value for some variable for that we use Read command while run script on local machine but I use the same command while run the script on remote machine but it's not working for me. How to use Read command for run script on remote machine?

sample code :

```
restore (){
        echo "Restore"
}

deploy () {
        echo "Deploy"
}


echo "Select any option to proceed..."
read opt
case $opt in

        restore)
        restore;
        break;;

        deploy)
        deploy;
        break;;
esac
```

This code work fine for when run scripts on local machine.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your question is quite vague. Could you post your script or at least tell about its purpose.

Comment: Hang on, why are you posting this again? What's the difference between this and your [previous question](http://askubuntu.com/q/712697/85695)?

Answer (score 1):

While this is probably possible, it is certainly not worth the effort. In any case, asking a user to interact with the script is (IMO) always a bad idea. This means you can never automate the use of the script and also creates problems like what you describe. It is usually better to pass the user's choice as an argument instead. You also don't want or need `break` inside a `case` statement

```
restore (){
        echo "Restore"
}

deploy () {
        echo "Deploy"
}

## read the 1st argument
case $1 in

        restore)
        restore;
        ;;

        deploy)
        deploy;
        ;;
esac
```

Then, run the script like this:

```
foo.sh restore
```

or

```
foo.sh deploy
```